# what is your opinion for the best function can be fitted to these plots?

Tags: approximation-theory, regression-analysis

I have three sets of data (x,f(x)) as follows:

```
setA={{0., -0.089772065541}, {0.405465108108, -0.108090184631}, \
{0.69314718056, -0.12075482495}, {1.09861228867, -0.136713310362}, \
{2.30258509299, -0.157557628096}, {3.91202300543, -0.124471537798}, \
{5.33271879327, -0.0801408424879}, {5.99146454711, -0.0626234699497}, \
{6.80239476332, -0.0451132549058}, {7.51534457118, -0.0332461226979}}

setB={{0., -2.73726021706}, {0.405465108108, -2.5635349861}, \
{0.69314718056, -2.45687874502}, {1.09861228867, -2.33885028583}, \
{2.30258509299, -2.25010185834}, {3.91202300543, -2.61123676241}, \
{5.33271879327, -3.14138743301}, {5.99146454711, -3.4084055453}, \
{6.80239476332, -3.74171459151}, {7.51534457118, -4.05221791235}}

setC={{0., -0.0513220378362}, {0.405465108108, -0.0598535159266}, \
{0.69314718056, -0.0628371387026}, {1.09861228867, -0.0622774482268}, \
{2.30258509299, -0.0396889415734}, {3.91202300543, -0.0121637513607}, \
{5.33271879327, -0.00330346154785}, {5.99146454711, \
-0.00172143838541}, {6.80239476332, -0.000717519675494}, \
{7.51534457118, -0.000325599564725}}
```

where their plots respectively are

[image]

[image]

[image]

I look for a function which can be fitted to these data and has small error. I tried the Morse function by Mathematica with the following form
$$
a (1 - \exp[-b (x - c)])^4 + d
$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are fit parameters. The fitted plot seem so good as follows respectively

[image]

[image]

[image]

but they have large errors up to 370% (specially in very small data) which is not good at all. As I'm not a mathematician and don't know large category of functions I decided to expose it to discussion in this site hoping that you (who know mathematics well) can help me by suggesting an appropriate function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "large errors up to 370%"?  The curve appears to fit your points reasonably well in all three diagrams, and certainly no points are off by a factor of 3 or so.

Comment: @user10354138 if you see setA, setB and setC, you can find some very small values such as 0.0003 or 0.0007, the slightest deviation from these small values can lead to large errors

Comment: If you care about relative errors in very small values, perhaps you should take logarithms first. (Or $\log(-y)$ if all your values are negative.)

Comment: In fact the first element of each inner set is Log of my original data. Now you think I should take Log again? or just Log[f(x)]?

Comment: Logarithms of the $f(x)$ values, before fitting a curve, because that way the curve-fitting gives equal weight to equal *relative* errors (= absolute errors of the logarithms).

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a polynomial function with the structure

$$
s(x,t) = \sum_{k=1}^nc_k(t)x^k
$$

with $c_k(t) = \sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_j t^j$ as follows in the MATHEMATICA script

```
grA = ListPlot[setA];
grB = ListPlot[setB];
grC = ListPlot[setC];

fA = Fit[setA, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x];
fB = Fit[setB, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x];
fC = Fit[setC, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x];

coeft[pol_, k_] := D[pol, {x, k}]/k! /. {x -> 0}

Ct = Table[Fit[{{0, coeft[fA, k]}, {1/2, coeft[fB, k]}, {1, coeft[fC, k]}}, {1, t, t^2}, t], {k, 0, 6}];

fun = Sum[Ct[[k]] x^(k - 1), {k, 1, 7}];

gr0 = Plot[{fun /. {t -> 0}, fun /. {t -> 1/2}, fun /. {t -> 1}}, {x, 0, 7.6}];
Show[gr0, grA, grB, grC]

Plot3D[fun, {x, 0, 7.6}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I had tried polynomial also, but 6 parameters are too much for my goal, for this reason I started to look for a well-known function can be fit to my data using a few parameters for example 3 or 4 finally.

Comment: "but 6 parameters are too much for my goal" - what is **your goal**? Instead of playing this guessing game you have so far put forward, what can you tell us about this data? What are you hoping to accomplish with the estimation. Over what range do you need to estimate this function, and what conditions does it need to meet in the range? Is there anything you can tell us about where the data comes from that would help in determining what would be a good form for the estimating function?